# Can't find PhraseRecognitionSubsystem (MRTK3)

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

As i said in the title, i can't find PhraseRecognitionSubsystem in MRTK3 section of Project Settings in Unity. I did install every single package of the MRTK3 with MixedRealityFeatureTool, but these are the only i can find in settings:

[image]

My Unity version is 2021.3.22

Thanks guys

I tried to reinstall all packages with tool but nothing. I doesn't pop up in settings